# Bootstrap way of dealing with multiple stacked wells

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started out using twitter bootstrap and so far I've had a nice experience.

I'm currently having some trouble with positioning some `.well` elements the way I'd like them to be. Basically, this is what I'd like to see them

[image]

But this is what I get

[image]

The second row is clearly overlapping the first one because the elements are floated and the row is not wrapped around the `.well` element. I tried to apply `.clearfix` class but sadly it did not fix this.

Here's the html I'm currently using

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row offset-top-large">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <a href="#" class="well well-lg">

            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row offset-top">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <a href="#" class="well well-lg">

            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.offset-top` classes just add additional margins to the rows

```
.offset-top-large{
    margin-top:100px;
}

.offset-top{
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

I know that I can fix this on my own by manipulating the css, like, removing the floats, for example, but **my question is** - can I do this (get the desired output) without adding any additional CSS and possibly breaking the bootstrap functionality (resizing to smaller screens etc.).

**Edit**

Sorry, I had posted the code with the wrong well size class - I have corrected it now and here is a fiddle displaying my problem - http://www.bootply.com/127620

Thanks!

Comment: I tried the code in JSFiddle and it is showing the desired output.

Comment: Me, too. Looks like it should. http://www.bootply.com/127615

Comment: Yeah the image of what's wrong appears to be without the css applied, is the question how to do it without modifying the margins like that?

Comment: I have edited the original post, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the html and css you provided, this has nothing to do with floats. The problem is that you only have link elements in your rows, which by default are inline elements. Inline elements don't take up any space in their container elements. Try adding display:block or display:inline-block to the well elements.

Comment: If you don't want to add display:block or display:inline-block to your  wells, make the well elements divs and wrap the wells in a link element. ex: <a href="#"><div class="well well-lg">Content</div></a>
As I mentioned in my answer before the problem is that you dont have any block level elements in your layout which causes the elements to have no height.

Answer (score 0):

The update to your question doesn't change a lot, you just need to increase the margin to account for the larger well size.

Try this:

```
.offset-top-large{
    margin-top:100px;
}

.offset-top{
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

Note: bantroth is also correct, adding `display:block` to your `a` tags is another solution.